# Delphi FireDAC with MS Access 2010 database. Why does it convert ACE to Jet?

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access-2010, delphi-xe7, firedac

I have converted a .mdb database to a .accdb database by following these steps:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-69abbf06-8401-4cf3-b950-f790fa9f359c
(using MS Access 2010)

After the conversion, the .accdb file starts with the following:
(database.accdb, file header viewed with hex editor), which is what I intended...

```
00 01 00 00 53 74 61 6E 64 61 72 64 20 41 43 45 20 44 42 00 02 00 00 00 B5 6E 03 62 60 09 C2 55 E9 A9 67 72 40 3F 00 9C 7E 9F 90 FF 85 9A 31 C5
....Standard ACE DB.....µn.b`.ÂUé©gr@?.œ~Ÿ.ÿ…š1Å
```

After opening the database, dropping a table, re-creating the table and doing some inserts with TFDConnection / TFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink / TFDBatchMove / TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader / TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter and the following code

```
  FAccessDB := TFDConnection.Create(Self);
  FAccessDB.Name := '';
  FAccessDB.Params.Clear;
  FAccessDB.Params.Add('DriverID=MSAcc_Direct');
  FAccessDB.LoginPrompt := False;

  // FDPhysMSAccessDriverLink1
  FFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink1 := TFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink.Create(Self);
  FFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink1.Name := '';
  FFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink1.DriverID := 'MSAcc_Direct';

  // Table_Out
  FFDTable_Out := TFDTable.Create(Self);
  FFDTable_Out.Name := '';
  FFDTable_Out.Connection := FAccessDB;

  // FDBatchMove1
  FFDBatchMove1 := TFDBatchMove.Create(Self);
  FFDBatchMove1.Name := '';
  FFDBatchMove1.OnError := FDBatchMove1Error;
  FFDBatchMove1.OnFindDestRecord := FDBatchMove1FindDestRecord;
  FFDBatchMove1.OnProgress := FDBatchMove1Progress;

  // FDBatchMoveDataSetReader1
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetReader1 := TFDBatchMoveDataSetReader.Create(Self);
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetReader1.Name := '';

  // FDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1 := TFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter.Create(Self);
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1.Name := '';

  // FDBatchMove1
  FFDBatchMove1.Reader := FFDBatchMoveDataSetReader1;
  FFDBatchMove1.Writer := FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1;
  FFDBatchMove1.Options := [poIdentityInsert];

  FAccessDB.Params.Values['Database'] := 'database.accdb';
  FAccessDB.Connected := True;
  aDropTableSQL := 'DROP TABLE ' + FTablenameDest;
  FAccessDB.ExecSQL(aDropTableSQL);
  FAccessDB.Commit;
  aCreateTableSQL := 'CREATE TABLE ' + FTablenameDest; // plus the rest 
                                              //of the create statement

  FFDTable_Out.TableName := FTablenameDest;
  FFDTable_Out.Active := True;
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetReader1.DataSet := FDataSetSrc; // a TDataset from 
                                                       // another database 
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1.DataSet := FFDTable_Out;
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1.Direct := True;

  FFDBatchMoveDataSetReader1.DataSet.Active := True;
  FFDBatchMoveDataSetWriter1.DataSet.Active := True;

  FFDBatchMove1.Mode := dmAlwaysInsert;
  FFDBatchMove1.Execute;
  FAccessDB.Commit;
  FAccessDB.Connected := False;

  FFDMSAccessService1 := TFDMSAccessService.Create(Self);
  FFDMSAccessService1.Name := '';

  FFDMSAccessService1.Database := 'database.accdb';
  FFDMSAccessService1.DestDatabase := 'database.accdb_temp.accdb';

  FFDMSAccessService1.DBVersion := avAccess2007;

  FFDMSAccessService1.Compact;   // <-- seems to convert here...
```

the file header of database.accdb becomes

```
00 01 00 00 53 74 61 6E 64 61 72 64 20 4A 65 74 20 44 42 00 01 00 00 00 B5 6E 03 62 60 09 C2 55 E9 A9 67 72 40 3F 00 9C 7E 9F 90 FF 85 9A 31 C5
....Standard Jet DB.....µn.b`.ÂUé©gr@?.œ~Ÿ.ÿ…š1Å
```

again, which it also was before conversion from .mdb to .accdb

it seems to me, that 'Standard Jet DB' means old format (.mdb)
and 'Standard ACE DB' means new format (.accdb)

Does FireDAC convert it back? why? 
How can I keep the new Access Format (.accdb, ACE DB)?

Comment: Is 'MSAcc_Direct' a third-party driver for FireDAC that directly manipulates Access database files? The FireDAC documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_Access_Database_%28FireDAC%29) only mentions 'MSAcc', which uses Access ODBC.

Comment: No, it is just the driverid of the driver-link-component, that I created named FFDPhysMSAccessDriverLink1 (see above code) with DriverID := 'MSAcc_Direct'.
It is no third party driver... I could have left out the component and just write 'MSAcc' instead.
Sometimes I use the driver-link-component to have special settings... here I use default settings.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found a fallback:
I would comment out the lines with FFDMSAccessService1.Compact; and use the msaccess.exe commandline: MSACCESS.EXE database.accdb /compact

but: is there a better (programmatic) solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just received an answer from Embarcadero (very fast answer, cool!):

Dmitry Arefiev wrote:
This is a known issue. At moment TFDMSAccessService does not really support avAccess2007.

--

With best regards,
Dmitry Arefiev / FireDAC Architect

Comment: Any new news on this?